# Necesito algo de ayuda con un login de PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login, encriptación

soy un estudiante de GRADO MEDIO de Sistemas Microinformáticos y Redes, bueno ahora en cuarentena nos ha tocado hacer un login con PHP pero estábamos acostumbrados a no encriptar las contraseñas en la base de datos.
Bueno yo tengo ya un register que me encripta las contraseñas

```
<?php

  $usuario= $_POST["usu"];
  $contrasenia= $_POST["contra"];

  $passs_cifrado=password_hash($contrasenia, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  try{

      $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secureblue', 'root', '');

      $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      


      $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios_pass (USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES (:usu, :contra)";

      $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);        


      $resultado->execute(array(":usu"=>$usuario, ":contra"=>$passs_cifrado));        


      echo "Registro insertado";

      $resultado->closeCursor();

  }catch(Exception $e){           


      echo "Línea del error: " . $e->getLine();

  }finally{

      $base=null;


  }

?>
```

Vale , y tengo este login con el siguiente index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/material.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" ></script>
</head>
<body class="cover">
    <div class="container-login">
        <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 80px;">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle"></i>
        </p>
        <p class="text-center text-condensedLight">Sign in with your Account</p>
        <form action="comprueba_login.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>INICIA SESION</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="izq">Login:</td> <td class="der"><input type="text" name="login"></input></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="izq">Contraseña:</td> <td class="der"><input type="password" name="contra"></input></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Iniciar Sesion"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y con este php para comprobar y hacer la consulta, pero este es muy basico y no se como ponerlo para que use la contraseña encriptada

```
    <?php

    try{

        $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secureblue" , "root", "");
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :contra";
        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));
        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
        $resultado->bindValue(":contra", $password);
        $resultado->execute();
        $numero_registros=$resultado->rowCount();

        if($numero_registros!=0){
            if(password_verify($password))
            header("location:home.php");
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];
        }else{

            header("location:index.php");

        }

    }catch(Exception $e){

        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());

    };
```

ASi es como esta el codigo del login

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    try{

        $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secureblue" , "root", "");
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :contra";
        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));

        // Cifrar para consultarla.
        $password2=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
        $resultado->bindValue(":contra", $password);
        $resultado->execute();
        $numero_registros=$resultado->rowCount();

        if($numero_registros!=0){
            if(password_verify($password))
            header("location:home.php");
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];
        }else{

            header("location:index.php");

        }

    }catch(Exception $e){

        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());

    };
```

Espero una ayuda lo antes posible y muchas gracias por todas las contribuciones que tienen todos a esta comunidad 
Un saludito a todos

Comment: Tengo poca experiencia con php, pero y si en vez de enviar el password original, cuando ejecutas la consulta SQL lo envias ya cifrado para comparar?

Comment: @cavpollo es que no se como hacerlo, en plan no se como reestructurar use sistema para que pueda volver a cifrar la contraseña y comparar, tengo una base muy mala por culpa del sistema educativo

Comment: Debes cifrarla e insertarla cifrada en la base de datos.

Comment: @Grommy ya la tengo cifrada en la base de datos pero lo que pasa es que no se como hacer el login para que descifre  la contraseña

Comment: Las contraseñas no deben descifrarse nunca, sino, un atacante que robase tu base de datos, podría hacer lo mismo. Tienes que cifrarlas, y cuando te envíen una contraseña nueva, debes cifrarla y comparar si existe alguna cifrada igual. Nunca descifrar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes cifrarla al consultar a la DB con el mismo algoritmo que antes. Sería algo así:

```
        $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :contra";
        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));

        // Cifrar para consultarla.
        $password=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
        $resultado->bindValue(":contra", $password);
```

Comment: Muchismas gracias eres un grande

Comment: he editado el codigo tal y como me has dicho pero al colocar la contraseña no sale de index.html y la contraseña es correcta

Comment: Eso significa que tu función de encriptado no produce la misma salida de cifrado dado el mismo texto para cifrar.

Comment: el primer codigo es como se cifra la contraseña y creo qye usa lo mismo, voy a editar el post y voy a poner como se me ha quedado lo del login y a ver si ves algún fallo, te lo agradecería mucho :)

Answer (score 1):

**password_verify** espera dos parametros, el password y el hash. El hash es lo que has almacenado en la bbdd asi que solo debes hacer un SELECT por el login y luego verificar el password con password_verify.

deberias hacer:

```
try{

    $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=secureblue" , "root", "");
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

    $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
    $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
    $resultado->execute();

    $numero_registros=$resultado->rowCount();

    if($numero_registros!=0){
        // falta el fetch
        $res = $resultado->fetch();

        if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $res['password'])) {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];
             header("location:home.php"); // location el ultimo, sino no te creara la sesion
        }
    }else{
        header("location:index.php");
    }

} catch (Exception $e){
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
};
```

Comment: Muchismas gracias :) eres un grande

Comment: Compi no me funciona eso bien , me da error

Comment: que error? se mas especifico.